# What is a good introduction to graph theory / algorithm

Tags: graph-theory

By good I mean minimal and essential.
One whose concepts form a minimum spanning tree, and whose words are precious :)

(A small pdf would be perfect)

Comment: I don't get the convex-optimization tag. If you want something  minimalist, what's wrong with Wikipedia?

Comment: wikipedia tries to be exhaustive and ends up sloppy. I would like something minimal, and carefully crafted.

Comment: Your question is slightly vague. Because of the enormity of Graph Theory as a subject, its difficult to point at a "all-in-one" minimal book. Nonetheless, see if [this](http://cr.yp.to/2005-261/bender2/GT.pdf) book helps.

Comment: I studied from this book: https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/even-alg.html. The first six chapters are available. It is very succinct and well written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not minimal but fairly good :)

I've collected some online resources. Pick the one you like:

http://karussell.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/free-online-graph-theory-books-and-resources/

Comment: interesting. I will send you a short one I found.

Answer (score 4):

A good book for you may be: Dieter Jungnickel, "Graphs, Networks and Algorithms", Third Edition, Springer, 2008

Answer (score 4):

If by "good introduction" you mean "just the basics", then you might want to look at the first chapter of "Graphs, Networks and Algorithms". Lucky you, springer gives the first chapter as a free preview: [here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-32278-5)

NB: I wanted to add this as a comment to @Jean-VictorCôté's answer but it seems I'm not reputable enough...